# Log in with form loaded with Ajax (scrapy): selenium vs scrapy-splash

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

To scrape the webpage I want, I need to log in. To access the log in form, I have to click on a button. This button makes an AJAX request, which displays the form.

I use Scrapy, with a middleware to pass my request through Tor and privoxy.

I have seen I could use selenium to click on the button but then (if I got it right), I can parse the response obtain by selenium with scrapy.

I have seen, I could use [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) with seems a better option. I have followed several tutos including this[one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VvFC93vAB7U), but I can't come up with a way to use scrapy-splash to click on a button to load the log in form and then to submit this form.

My settings.py: (I didn't set HTTP_PROXY)

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    ...
    'project.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 100,}
```

My middlewares.py

```
def set_new_ip():
    with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
        controller.authenticate(password="***") 
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)

set_new_ip() # request new IP from TOR
request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8118'  # this passes the resquest through privoxy
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ProxyMiddleware` and `request.meta['proxy']`.

Use [proxy-profiles](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#proxy-profiles) instead.